# POST parameters parsed - PUT not / LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, rest, post, put

I'm having difficulties passing parameters to a LAMP server:

- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
- curl 7.22.0

On the server side, I use slim for REST operations. It seems to work fine for GET/POST. My test implementation looks like this:

```
 // Check the post route
 $app->post('/data', function () use ($app) {
        $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        $json_new_array["input"] = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
        $json_new_string = json_encode($json_new_array);
        echo $json_new_string;
    });

 // Check the put route
 $app->put('/data', function () use ($app) {
         $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
         $json_new_array["input"] = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
         $json_new_string = json_encode($json_new_array);
         echo $json_new_string;
    });
```

Here is what I've been trying on the client side to pass parameters:

```
curl -X PUT http://hostname/001_mockserver.php/data -d fruit=orange -d quantity=4 -i
```

and

```
curl -X POST http://hostname/001_mockserver.php/data -d fruit=orange -d quantity=4 -i
```

The **PUT** attempt returns in `{"input":""}` while **POST** behavior is as expected:  `{"input":"fruit=orange&quantity=4"}`

I read that apache shouldn't be an issue. So any suggestions where to start?

Comment: I suspect the problem is not with your code but with the request - the `-d` option is intended for creating a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body for a POST request, using it with a PUT may confuse cURL and cause it to send an empty body. Try uploading a file using the `-T` option instead, or test using something like [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/). It would also be worth using a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the raw data being sent.

Comment: Hi Dave. Not sure if I got your message. I am bot trying to upload anything, I'm just trying to pass two parameters ... however, I shall give Wireshark a try

Comment: That's exactly the point - PUT requests are not designed for passing parameters, they are designed for passing blocks of data (usually files).

Comment: I used POSTER to send the parameter as JSON & file: application/json and I got just the same result: POST gets through, PUT doesn't :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I've figured it out:

```
// Check the put route
$app->put('/data', function () use ($app) {
         $request = $app->request();
         $body = $request->getBody();
  });
```

does the job :-D